Why did General Groves mention the baby delivery count here?
In the scene, an aquarium bowl filled with marbles is shown, followed by Robert and General Groves walking outside Los Alamos. Robert inquires about the progress of their work, to which
General Groves responds with a rhetorical question about the two years and a billion dollars’
worth of investment:

ROBERT: Well, hard to put a price on it.
General Groves: Not really, just add up the bills. "Rural free
deliveries."  Eighty babies delivered the first year. This year, we've
had ten a month.

Why did General Groves mention the baby delivery count here?

This comes directly from the source biography American Prometheus: The Triumph and Tragedy of J. Robert Oppenheimer.
Groves is clearly distressed at the spiralling costs of running what almost immediately became a boom town, with a rapidly increasing population of non-scientists.

INSIDE THE BARBED WIRE, Kitty sometimes felt as if she were living
under a microscope. The Army commissary often had foods and goods
available on the outside only with a ration card. The theater showed
two movies a week for only 15 cents a show. Medical care was free. So
many young couples had babies—some eighty births were recorded the
first year, and about ten a month thereafter—that the small seven-room
hospital was labeled “RFD,” for “rural free delivery.” When General
Groves complained about all the new babies, Oppenheimer wryly observed
that the duties of a scientific director did not include birth
control. And that was also true for the Oppenheimers. By then, Kitty
was pregnant again. On December 7, 1944, she gave birth in the Los
Alamos barracks hospital to a daughter, Katherine, whom they nicknamed
“Tyke.” A sign was posted over the crib saying “Oppenheimer,” and for
several days people filed by to take a peek at the boss’s baby girl.

The Rural Free Delivery service was a postal service that gave 'free delivery' to Americans living in areas away from the normal postal routes, hence the joke.
